# How to open an .exe file using gwt?

Tags: java, gwt, exe

I am using gwt to develop java project. I want to open .exe file that is installed on client machine. I have searched on internet but didn't find a suitable solution.

Comment: You can't run exe files from the browser. Java is translated to javascript.

Comment: Try it using `Applet`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access any files on a user's computer from a web browser. Otherwise, every computer in the world could be be easily hacked.

You can offer a user to install a program, and then ask this user to start this program, but you cannot install and run this program yourself.

Comment: I don't want to install the program in user's machine I just wanted to start a program installed on user's machine with user's permission to open it from browser.

Comment: You can't. A user can start it, but not from the browser. What program do you want to start and why?

Comment: I am developing a web project that allow user to scan files and upload to server and i have a scanner application in exe format that will scan and upload the files on server. I want to open that exe file to run when user clicks on scan button. I have previously developed the scanner application so i thought opening that file from web project will save time of developing the scanner application again.

Answer (score 1):

No its not possible

At least it is not specific for GWT in comparison with other Javascript ways to do this. i.e : If there is a way to do this then it is a huge bug and security flaw in the browser.

You can offer the file for download and let the user execute it. But I guess that is not what you want.